# print number in some digits

Tags: c, printf

I want to print number according to input N.

As the range of N increases, I'll be so messed up.

Is there another solution easier than this?

If someone helps me, i'll really appreciate it. Thanks!

```
     if (N == 3) {
        for (int a = 0; a < N; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
                printf("%03d ",y[a][b]);
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (N == 4) {
        for (int a = 0; a < N; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
                printf("%04d ", y[a][b]);
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (N == 5) {
        for (int a = 0; a < N; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
                printf("%05d ", y[a][b]);
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (N == 6) {
        for (int a = 0; a < N; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
                printf("%06d ", y[a][b]);
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int a = 0; a < N; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
                printf("%07d ", y[a][b]);
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just construct the format string using your value and then use it to print. A format string doesn't need to be a string literal.

Comment: It would be nice to show an example input & output of what you want...

Comment: Use `printf("%0*d ", N, y[a][b])`

Comment: @Tibrogargan Nice one. Put it in an answer.

Comment: wow! Thanks EB! it's really helpful for me

Answer (score 3):

Use the `*` width argument specifier of the `printf` format (Assumption: N is an int)

```
// for all values of N:
for (int a = 0; a < N; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
        printf("%0*d ", N, y[a][b]);
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for (int a = 0; a < N; a++) { 
    for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++) { 
        printf("%0*d ",N, y[a][b]); 
    } 
    cout << endl; 
}
```

I typed solution by phone. Will test it when i open my pc

This is called dynamic width specifier. [Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

> width description
>
> (number)Minimum number of characters to be printed.
>   If the value to be printed is shorter than this number, the result is
>   padded with blank spaces. The value is not truncated even if the
>   result is larger.
>
> *The width is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be
>   formatted.